# What is the mechanism behind startActivityForResult() in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity. In this activity I want to start another activity using startActivityForResult(). I understand that my basic activity is started within a process with a main GUI thread. 
But as far as I understand, startActivityForResult() is asynchronious which means that my new activity will be executed in a different thread. 
I can't find information regarding the threads inside. If there is only one GUI thread, how does these functions work asynchroniously ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But as far as I understand,
>   startActivityForResult() is
>   asynchronious which means that my new
>   activity will be executed in a
>   different thread.

`startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous. That does not mean that your new activity will be executed in a different thread. If the new activity is part of your own application, it runs on the main application thread, like all your other activities.

> If there is only one GUI thread, how does these functions work asynchroniously ?

`startActivityForResult()`, like `startActivity()`, does not do anything immediately. Rather, it puts a message on a message queue, then returns. When you return control back to Android (e.g., your `onClick()` method ends), Android goes back to processing messages off of that queue. When it gets to your start-activity message, it starts up the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

pass any info you want in the form of Extras in your Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClass.class);
i.putExtra("EXTRA_INFO", <your info here>);
startActivityForResult(i);
```

And in your new activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      if(getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_INFO"){
         mString =  getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_INFO");
      } 
}
```