# Difference Between Synchronous Activities ans ASynchronous Activities

Tags: android

Please tell me the Difference Between Synchronous Activities ans ASynchronous Activities..
and also about that

-startActivity() is Synchronous or Asynchronous

-startActivityForResult() is Synchronous or Asynchronous

and why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From first principles, synchronous activities means that Activity A operation will depend on activity B eg(coordinating to work with a shared param)  Asynchronous  activities means that the operation of two activities are totally disconnected.

Comment: so thanx... and plz also tell me about startActivity() and startActivityForResult().. which is synchronous and which is asynchromous.. i have search from google.. both opinions are there.. m confuse.. please guide me

Comment: @Jordan : Please Ans the rest of the Question.

Comment: @Adnan Hi.. Jordan has clearly answered the question's concept. startActivity() does not expect any result from the called activity, so it is asynchronous(you may destroy the calling activity if you want to). But start ActivityForResult() is synchronous because the calling activity depends on the called activity's result!

Answer (score 3):

According to my general  concept **both startActvity() and startActivityForResult() are asynchronus**   as in the synchronus Activity the current activity will depend on the new activity.

For example :

suppose in current actvity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
startAcivity(i); //or startActivityForResult(i,0);
Log.v("First","Activity");
```

Now for any activity to be synchronus the later part of the current acivity (once the new activity is started) must be executed after the onCreate method of the new actvity(here Second class).

But generally this never happens. I mean the later part of the current Activity( once a new acivity is started by calling startActivity() or StartResultForActivity()) is never depended on the onCreate method of the New activity.

for more you can go through these links :

[What is the mechanism behind startActivityForResult() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489164/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-startactivityforresult-in-android)

http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-12/msg04249.html

Hope from the above example you understood exactly what startActivity() & StartResultForActivity() are  and what is synchronus & asynchronus Actvity is....:)

Comment: my question is simply this..            Which of the following are true?
a. Both startActivity and startSubActivity start an activity synchronously.
b. Both startActivity and startActivityForResults start an activity asynchronously.
c. startActivity is an asynchronously call, but startSubActivity is synchronous.
d. startActivity is a synchronous call, but startSubActivity is asynchronous.