# Synchronous and asynchronous activities

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, synchronous

Can anyone help me to understand **synchronous** and **asynchronous** activities in Android?

What is exactly meant by synchronous and asynchronous activity in Android?

`StartActivity`, `StartSubActivity` and `StartAcivityForResult` start an activity  synchronously or asynchronously, or can they behave in both ways?

Please explain as I have gone through many articles but could not find any proper explaination over this.

Comment: @Dinesh..Your question is same as [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613295/difference-between-synchronous-activities-ans-asynchronous-activities[link] and also you have replied on this post. So why you are asking the same question.Moreover AFAIK startSubActivity is never released in public and it's functionality is provided by startActivityForResult()

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the comment. I replied that question but i m still little confused over this concept. So want to be 100% clear. If you have some Idea over this than you can share with me ...:)

Comment: "Can anyone help me to explain Synchronous and ASynchronous Activity in android." -- there is no such concept in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare : what ever the user is doing in an activity - there is a UI thread which is running, at-least, so according to you an activity is a process or just collection of few threads out of a process for the Application?

Comment: @Bhuro: An activity is a Java class. It is neither a process nor a collection of a few threads.

Comment: ok,  @CommonsWare I mean at the time of executing by system ... ?? As it is  a Java class, there mill be an object, the object is performing any function... as a part of process, or thread ???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, only one activity can be running at a time on Android, so you'll never have two activities running at the same time. Use `startActivity()` when you want to "fire and forget", that is, you want to launch an activity but are not expecting it to return a value to your activity. In that case, the new activity will start and your activity will be paused; you might eventually regain control once the user returns to your activity.

Use `startActivityForResult()` when you are expecing a result from the activity you are launching. In this case, the calling activity should override `onActivityResult()`, which will be called when the launched activity exits and has a result to return to you (which it sets with `setResult()`).

In both cases, since the calling activity and the called activity are in the same *task*, it's "synchronous" in a certain sense (although I think using the terms "synchronous" and "asynchronous" can be confusing in this context). The calling activity won't appear on the screen until the called activity finishes.

A useful read to know more is:
* http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

-
Bruno Oliveira (Android Developer Relations, Google)

Comment: Thanks Bruno for a quick reply. But can just explain me in what sense the term "synchronous" and "asynchronous" are used for as I have seen in many places these type of question arises....

Comment: Synchronous means that execution will not continue until a certain task is finished. If `startActivity` worked this way, all the interface would freeze until the other activity was running. Asynchronous means that your task will take place somewhere in the future, and execution continues in the meanwhile: you request that an Activity be started, and your code continues to execute knowing that it will eventually happen.

Comment: The answer is not addressing the question properly.

Comment: What is the use of `setResult` ? It only returns void and only takes requestCode and an `Intent?` object as parameter. How would you pass the data using `setResult` ?

Comment: I am simply creating my own functions. And calling those functions inside the onActivityResult() and passing the data processed in the onActivityResult() as parameters to the functions. I dont find any use case for `setResult`